# How to load a .js file UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I want to load .js(javaScript) file in UIWebView not only one function like

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *javaScript=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"javascript" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

[1] http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22703-loading-local-javascript-file-into-uiwebview-problem.html

[2] http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview